# What are the dangers of making an extra wall socket on a circuit?

Tags: power, current, socket

Given that one has a basement room on an apartment complex running a single set of cables to power a quite noticeably dim lamp. Given also that the cables do provide 220v, what are the risks of cutting the cables and creating an extra wall socket and running just one of these appliances (there is no wall socket at all, the cables were just "meant" to power the dim light):

-Fridge (small spikes on current)

-Microwave

-Desktop computer (stable current withdrawn)

I imagine that the danger here is on how many watts (i.e. how much current) the cables can support before over heating, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to ask about the dangers, then **Don't Mess with the Wiring**.

You don't say where you are. Different locales have different rules about civilians messing with their own mains wiring. Generally, they are to keep people from killing themselves, either immediately through shock, or later via fires.